Getting black image from pi camera. libcamera-still working fine
def getImg(display=False, size=[480, 240], skip_frames=30):
    for _ in range(skip_frames):
        cap.read()  # Skip frames to stabilize the camera
    _, img = cap.read()
    if img is None:
        print("Failed to capture image. Retrying...")
        return None
    img = cv2.resize(img, (size[0], size[1]))
    if display:
        cv2.imshow('IMG', img)
    return img

I am trying to train a model so for that I am collecting images using pi camera with raspberry pi but got black images. The pi camera work fine with libcamera-still.
I have tried to skip the frames. from 10 to 30 frames but not worked.

Please ensure your example is complete, see [mcve].

Please read [ask] and then edit to provide a [mcve]. Right now you only provided a small code snippet with nothing else.
